# "0.4 miles away" or "0.4 mile away"

Tags: grammatical-number

Is it "0.4 miles away" or "0.4 mile away"?

My intuition tells the first form is correct, but a colleague isn't convinced.

Comment: It’s zero point four miles but four tenths of a mile.

Comment: Any number point any number is plural.